# Find the value of $6P_{10} - 15P_8 + 10P_6+7$ for $P_n=\sin^n x+\cos^n x$

Tags: trigonometry

If $P_n=\sin^n x+\cos^n x$ where $n$ is a whole number and $x$ is a real number.

Find the value of $6P_{10} - 15P_8 + 10P_6+7$

I tried this: $$P_6 \Longrightarrow \sin^6 x + \cos^6 x = (\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)^3 - 3\sin^2 x \cos^2 x \Longrightarrow 1 - 3 \sin^2 x \cos^2 x.$$ However I have no clue how to calculate the ones of powers 8 and 10. please help.

Comment: So the question is $$6(\sin^{10} x + \cos^{10} x) - 15(\sin^8 x + \cos^8 x) +10(\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x)+7$$ ??

Comment: When you pose a question here, you should indicate what you have attempted and where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Ritwik Sinha, that is exactly my question.

N.F. Taussig, I haven't even been able to attempt the question. It's just those huge powers like 10 and 8 which scare me. However, I was able to solve the one with the powers of 6.

Comment: @ShreshtaS What did you get when you solved for power 6 ? write it up. Don't worry about down votes they are not to discourage you. If you provide your work, those -5's will +5 in no time.

Comment: @ritwik sinha 

Well I did this, P(subscript) 6
=> sin^6 x + cos^6 x = (sin^2 x + cos^2 x)^3 - 3sin^2 x cos^2 x
=> 1 - 3 sin^2 x cos^2 x.

However i have no clue how to calculate the ones of powers 8 and 10.

Comment: @ShreshtaS edit the question, write it there.

Comment: @ritwik sinha, I've done it sir. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
 Set $p=\sin x\cos x=\frac12\sin 2x$ and prove the relation:
$$P_n=P_nP_2=P_{n+2}+p^2P_{n-2}.$$

*An example:*

\begin{align*}P_4&=(\sin^4x+\cos^4x)(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)\\
&=\sin ^6x+\sin^4x\cos^2x+\cos^4x\sin^2x+\cos^6x\\
&=\sin ^6x+\cos^6x+\sin^2x\cos^2x(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)\\
&=P_6+\sin^2x\cos^2x.\end{align*}
Now 
$$P_4=\sin^4x+\cos^4x=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^2-2\sin^2x\cos^2x=1-2\sin^2x\cos^2x,$$
so that
$$P_6=P_4-\sin^2x\cos^2x=1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x.$$
By the same method, you'll deduce $P_8$ from $P_6$ and  ultimately $P_{10}$ from $P_8$.

Comment: I could not do it sir. Could you please provide more hints?

Comment: @Shreshta S: I've added a worked out example. Is it clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q(u)=u^4(u^2-1)^2$. Then we have if $F(x)$ is your expression, that the derivative of $F(x)$ is:

$$F(x)^{\prime}=60\sin(x)\cos(x)(Q(\sin(x))-Q(\cos(x)))=0$$
It is easy to finish.

Added:

Let the first part be $A=6(\sin(x))^{10}-15(\sin(x))^8+10(\sin(x))^6$ Then we compute the derivative of $A$, it is
$$60\cos(x)(\sin(x))^9-120\cos(x)(\sin(x))^7+60\cos(x)(\sin(x))^5=60\cos(x)\sin(x)Q(\sin(x))$$

In  the same way, the derivative of $B=6(\cos(x))^{10}-15(\cos(x))^8+10(\cos(x))^6$ is $-60\sin(x)\cos(x)Q(\cos(x))$. Hence, as it is clear that $Q(\sin(x))=Q(\cos(x))=(\sin(x)^4\cos(x)^4$, we find that $F^{\prime}(x)=0$, hence $F$ is constant. Then compute $F$ for $x=0$.

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't do it, could you please give me a more detailed hint?

Comment: @Shreshta I have given a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

For $n \ge 4$, 
we have
$$P_n-P_{n-2}$$
$$=\cos^n \theta +\sin^n \theta -(\cos^{n-2} \theta +\sin^{n-2} \theta$$
$$=\cos^{n-2} \theta (\cos^2 \theta-1) +\sin^{n-2} \theta(\sin^2\theta-1)$$
$$=-\sin^2\theta\cos^{n-2} \theta  -\cos^2\theta\sin^{n-2} \theta$$
$$=-\sin^2\theta \cos^{2}\theta(\cos^{n-4} \theta +\sin^{n-4} \theta)$$
$$=-\sin^2\theta \cos^2\theta P_{n-4}$$

Now 
$$6(P_{10} -P_8) -9(P_8-P_6)+(P_{6} -P_{4})+(P_4 -P_{2})+ 8$$

$$=-\sin^2\theta \cos^2\theta (6P_6 -9P_4+P_{2} +P_0) +8$$
$$=-3\sin^2\theta \cos^2\theta(2P_6 -3P_4) -\sin^2\theta \cos^2\theta(1+2 )+8 $$

When you calculate $2P_6 -3P_4$ you will get it is equal to $-1$

$$=-3\sin^2\theta \cos^2\theta(-1) -3\sin^2\theta \cos^2\theta+8 $$
$$=8$$

Comment: how is 
cos^{n-2} \theta (\cos^2 \theta) +\sin^{n-2} \theta(\sin^2\theta-1) = -\sin^2\theta \cos^{n-2}(\cos^{n-4} \theta +\sin^{n-4} \theta) ? I did not understand that part.

Comment: @ShreshtaS It was to typographical error. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying find how the coefficients of $P_n, n=6,8,10$ were identified.

Let $P_{2n}=Q_n$ so that we need to find $$6Q_5-15Q_4+10Q_3+7$$

Writing  $a=\cos^2x\sin^2x$ and using [Recurrence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving), $$Q_{m+2}-Q_{m+1}-aQ_m=0$$

Now $Q_0=2,Q_1=1$

$Q_2=1-2a$

$Q_3=Q_2-aQ_1=1-3a$

$Q_4=Q_3-aQ_2=\cdots=1-4a+2a^2$

$Q_5=Q_4-aQ_3=\cdots=1-5a+5a^2$

To eliminate $a^2,$   $$2Q_5-5Q_4=\cdots=10a-3$$

To eliminate $a,$ $$3(2Q_5-5Q_4)+10\cdot Q_3=\cdots=1$$